# PHP DOM html get element from another element

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to create something for php html dom to work with a element path pattern.

It looks as fallow. I can have different paths where I want to have some text out. like;

```
$elements = 'h1;span;';
$elements = 'div.test;h2;span';
```

I tried to create an function to handle these inserts but I am stuck on the
part to set 'getElementsByTagName()' in the good order and to receive the value of
the last element,

what I have done now;

```
    function convertName($html, $elements) {

        $elements = explode(';', $elements);
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
        $name = null;

        foreach ($elements as $element) :
            $name. = getElementsByTagName($element)->item(0)->;
            endforeach;

         $test = $dom->$name.'nodeValue';
         print_r($test); // receive value          
   }
```

I hope someone can give me some input or examples.

Comment: you want to familiarize with [XPath](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html) or use a third party lib supporting Selector, e.g. phpQuery or Zend_Dom

Comment: I dont want to put an lib with a big class for this thing, I think there has to be a solution to reach this in a simple way :)

Comment: sorry, I just got it, thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 1):

May be something like this:

```
function convertName($html, $elements) {
   $doc = new DOMDocument();
   libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
   $doc->loadHTML($html); // loads your html
   $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

   $elements = explode(';', $elements);
   $elemValues = array();

   foreach ($elements as $element) {
      $nodelist = $xpath->query("//$element");
      for($i=0; $i < $nodelist->length; $i++)
         $elemValues[$element][] = $nodelist->item($i)->nodeValue;
   }
   return $elemValues;
}

// TESTING
$html = <<< EOF
 <span class="bar">Some normal Text</span>
 <input type="hidden" name="hf" value="123">
 <h1>Heading 1<span> span inside h1</span></h1>
 <div class='foo'>Some DIV</div>
 <span class="bold">Bold Text</span>
 <p/>
EOF;

$elements = 'h1;span;';
// replace all but last ; with / to get valid XPATH
$elements = preg_replace('#;(?=[^;]*;)#', '/', $elements);
// call our function
$elemValues = convertName($html, $elements);
print_r($elemValues);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [h1/span] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  span inside h1
        )

)
```

Comment: Its almost like this but return is separated, this one will give all <span> results back found in the document. When the $elements is 'h1;span', it means I just want to take the nodeValue out of 'span' in the 'h1'.

Comment: Are you saying `h1;span` is your version of XPATH to the span inside h1? If that's the case above code easily be tweaked. Pls see my update.